# One <p:dialog> for multiple beans

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have a `<p:dialog>` in my general layout. I have its `Header` attribute hardcoded at the moment.

What I want is to access it from different beans and change its `Header` at run-time according to my choice.

I am using it to show a loading message to the user at the moment and want to update the loading text according to the current backend processing, e.g "waiting for server's response" etc.

```
<p:dialog id="main-status-dialog"
          widgetVar="mainStatusDialog"
          modal="true"
          header="Loading..."
          draggable="false"
          closable="false"
          resizable="false"
          appendToBody="true">
```

Now I am calling it from different JSF pages on button clicks e.g `<h:link outcome="/generalInformation" value="General Information" onclick="mainStatusDialog.show()" />`
It works fine but always Show me "Loading..." because I have a hardcoaded Attribute. So how can I make it dynamic? Please note that I don't want to do it only for one page or bean, but from any page it Access it, i can Change ist Header accordingly.
Thanks!

Comment: Some code would help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a managed property with **[@ManagedProperty](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/bean/ManagedProperty.html)** of one of your managed beans (e.g `HeaderBean`)and change it every time accordingly and set the header value to this value, and it whould look dynamically updated.

```
@ManagedProperty("#{headerBean}")
private HeaderBean headerBean;
```

And in your header managed bean make a `String` property `value` where you will store the value of the header:

```
@ManagedBean(name = "headerBean")
@RequestScoped
public class HeaderBean implements Serializable
{
    private String value = null;

    // getter and setter methods
```

And in your `p:dialog`:

```
<p:dialog id="main-status-dialog"
      widgetVar="mainStatusDialog"
      modal="true"
      header="#{headerBean.value}"
      draggable="false"
      closable="false"
      resizable="false"
      appendToBody="true">
```

Take a look at the following liks to find more about it:

1. **[The BalusC Code: Communication in JSF 2.0](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2011/09/communication-in-jsf-20.html)**
2. **[Injecting Managed beans in JSF 2.0](http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/injecting-managed-beans-in-jsf-2-0/)**
3. **[@ManagedProperty - Inject one request scoped bean into another request scoped bean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5648299/managedproperty-inject-one-request-scoped-bean-into-another-request-scoped-be)**

### EDIT:

You can use `RequestContext` to update the dialog from your beans, If you take a look at [**Better ajax operations and callbacks in JSF with PrimeFaces**](http://yigitdarcin.com/2011/05/18/better-ajax-operations-and-callbacks-in-jsf-with-primefaces/) you will see that:

> **RequestContext API** enables developers to do 2 simple things. 1st you can tell what you want to update in the xhtml based on conditions in actions that you define in your Managed Beans.To update a component from serverside, you can just write:

The code you need to update the p:dialog from your managed beans is:

```
RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().
          addPartialUpdateTarget("header_id");
```

You can also use update attribute in your commandLink like this:

```
<h:link outcome="/generalInformation" value="General Information" oncomplete="mainStatusDialog.show()" update=":main-status-dialog"/>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. I tried but it didn't update the Header. May be I have to update the Dialog after changing the message?

Comment: of course you have to update the dialog so the header will be changed.

Comment: then for this I have to do something from bean. can you give me the code how i can Access the Dialog in bean an update it?

Comment: it worked with RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().update( "main-status-dialog" ); but the Problem is when I Change it, the value becomes permanently changed. Also it doesn't Change the value live when a previous Dialog is already displaing. I have tried it with @RequestScoped, view and session but same results.

Comment: As far as I know you can't do it permanently, you can either use an update attribute with another component such as a link, take a look at [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10659389/primefaces-how-to-update-content-in-a-dialog-and-keep-the-dialog-centered) or like I mentioned with  RequestContext .

Comment: Thanks for the answer, tough it hasn't solved my issue completely but it was helpfull :)